# Searching public Outlook contacts folder from C#

Tags: c#, outlook, contacts

We have a large public contacts folder in Outlook called Global Contacts, I'd like to be able to search through it and return a number of results that match certain criteria, ideally wildcard-style.

E.g. if someone puts "je" in the 'name' textbox, it will return all contacts whose names contain 'je'. This may be coupled as an AND with a companyname textbox.

Most of the examples I've seen are either in VB, or are concerned with doing this form a web app - I'm doing a winforms app, and every machine has Outlook 2002 installed (yeah, I know, update long overdue).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Some code would be nice as a place to start.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application objOutlook; //declare Outlook application
            objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); //create it
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace objNS = objOutlook.Session; //create new session
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oAllPublicFolders; //what it says on the tin
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder oPublicFolders; // as above
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder objContacts; //as above
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items itmsFiltered; //the filtered items list
            oPublicFolders = objNS.Folders["Public Folders"];
            oAllPublicFolders = oPublicFolders.Folders["All Public Folders"];
            objContacts = oAllPublicFolders.Folders["Global Contacts"];

            itmsFiltered = objContacts.Items.Restrict(strFilter);//restrict the search to our filter terms
```

Then just looping through itmsFiltered to add it to an ObjectListView. Hopefully this will be of use to someone else looking to do the same - it took me a while to cobble this together from various sources.

Answer (score 1):

to find contacts folder you can iterate items of olFolderContacts. Here is the code

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

namespace RyanCore
{
    public class Loader
    {
        public static ContactsViewModel LoadModel(Application objOutlook)
        {
            var viewModel = new ContactsViewModel();

            MAPIFolder fldContacts = objOutlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
            foreach (object obj in fldContacts.Items)
            {
                if (obj is _ContactItem)
                {
                    var contact = (_ContactItem) obj;
                    viewModel.Contacts.Add(new Contact(contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName, contact.Email1Address));
                }
                else if (obj is DistListItem)
                {
                    var distListItem = (DistListItem) obj;
                    var contactGroup = new ContactGroup(distListItem.Subject);

                    viewModel.Groups.Add(contactGroup);
                    for (Int32 i = 1; i <= distListItem.MemberCount; i++)
                    {
                        Recipient subMember = distListItem.GetMember(i);
                        contactGroup.Contacts.Add(new Contact(subMember.Name, subMember.AddressEntry.Address));
                    }
                }
            }
            return viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```